# onserverclick not firing c# when properties added in runtime

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I'm adding a button in runtime in C# web forms. I need to call a function btnEdit_click when the button is called. Somehow the function isn't being called.

The codes are below. Please help

```
        protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Setup.aspx");
    }

                HtmlGenericControl EditButton = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
                EditButton.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-default";
                EditButton.Attributes["id"] = "editButton";
                EditButton.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
                EditButton.Attributes["OnServerClick"] = "btnEdit_Click";
                EditButton.InnerText = "Edit";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     </form>
  </body>
  </html>



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlButton EditButton = new HtmlButton();
        EditButton.Attributes["class"] = "btn btn-default";
        EditButton.Attributes["id"] = "editButton";
        EditButton.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        EditButton.InnerText = "Edit";
        EditButton.ServerClick += btnEdit_Click;

        this.form1.Controls.Add(EditButton);
    }
    protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Setup.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: I figured it out sometime back, but it Works. thanks!!